# Issue creating a new user / schema in Oracle 11G instance

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have an Oracle instance with 8 users/schemas already but since late last week I am unable to create any new users on that instance. When I run the create user script it just keeps running....

This is a development box and I have full access to it. I am not a DBA so how do I troubleshoot to find out what the issue could be? and what could the issue be?

Here is the create user script:

```
create user usr_ARCHIVE identified by usr_ARCHIVEpw
default tablespace USERS
temporary tablespace TEMP
profile DEFAULT
quota UNLIMITED on USERS;
```

Comment: Please post your user creation script. Have you tried creating a new user using Enterprise manager?

Comment: Here is the create user script:
    create user usr_ARCHIVE identified by usr_ARCHIVEpw
    default tablespace USERS
    temporary tablespace TEMP
    profile DEFAULT
    quota UNLIMITED on USERS;

Comment: @Ram: Post the error message when running that script.

Comment: @Gaurav - I am not getting any errors, I run the script and it runs forever not completing.

Comment: @Ram - is there anything in the alert log? Are you able to log in as other (non-SYS) users? Only thing that immediately comes to mind is that the redo log can't rotate (archive log dest full, maybe), but you'd see symptoms of that everywhere, unless - perhaps - you'd only connected as SYS.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the user tablespace to see whether it has enough free space or not. I have faced similar issues in the past.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably waiting or trying to obtain a lock. To determine what is going on you need to enable tracing. Before executing the create user statement, execute the following command:

```
alter session set events '10046 trace name context forever, level 12';
```

This will create a trace file in the trace directory. By default this is the same directory where the alert.log file is stored. Analyze the trace file and especially check for the lines that start with WAIT.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with another 10G TNSListener that was running. Once the 10G TNSListener was stopped and 11G Listener restarted the issue was resolved.